# How to make a GET operation where you send an API key and code in header?

Tags: java, android

I would like to be able to get values from a server by using their API, to be able to do that I have to send an API-key and an API-Code in the header, I have tried with Retrofit to be able to use annotations but with no luck, so if anyone can look through the code and point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it!

Below I will add some code examples:

APIService

```
public interface APIService {

@GET("/temperature")
@Headers({"api-key: "my api key", "code: "my-api-code"})
Call<Post> getTemperature();
```

ApiUtils

```
public class ApiUtils {

private ApiUtils() {}

public static final String BASE_URL = "my url";

public static APIService getAPIService() {

    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
}
```

Retrofit Client

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private TextView mResponseTv;

private APIService mAPIService;

@NonNull
private CompositeDisposable mDisposables;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText titleEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_title);
    final EditText bodyEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_body);
    Button submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    mResponseTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_response);

    mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

    mDisposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String title = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
            String body = bodyEt.getText().toString().trim();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(body)) {
                sendPost(title, body);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void showErrorMessage() {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.mssg_error_submitting_post, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void getTemperature() {
    mAPIService.getTemperature().enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse(response.body().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
            showErrorMessage();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What version of Retrofit are you using?

Comment: Should probably have clarified that in my original text, but I am using Retrofit 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Retrofit 2 you can try this

```
public interface APIService {

@GET("/temperature")
Call<Post> getTemperature(@Header("api-key") String my_api_key, @Header("code") String my-api-code);
```

And pass codes in your call